How to make that SAT collision algo implementation work for walls?
I wrote Separating Axis Theorem (SAT) algorithm implementation for collisions in my SFML game by one of the OneLoneCoder video tutorials on YouTube. But it doesn't work for wall colliders, the problem is on video
I understand this algorithm, but seems like my resolving is not working properly. I want to prevent player from going outside the walls. So how can I do this? My code:
// the function returns displacement that player(which has collider sf::ConvexShape a)
//      should move by to resolve collision
sf::Vector2f Collision::is_colliding_SAT_resolve(sf::ConvexShape& a, sf::ConvexShape& b, float dt)
{
    float overlap = std::min(find_min_overlap(a, b), find_min_overlap(b, a));
    if (overlap >= 0) {
        sf::Vector2f d = (b.getPosition() - a.getPosition());
        float s = sqrtf(d.x * d.x + d.y * d.y);
        if (s != 0)
            return { overlap * d.x * dt / s, overlap * d.y * dt / s };
    }
    return { 0,0 };
}

float Collision::find_min_overlap(sf::ConvexShape& a, sf::ConvexShape& b)
{
    float overlap = std::numeric_limits<float>::max();
    std::vector<sf::Vector2f> va(a.getPointCount()), vb(b.getPointCount());

    for (int i = 0; i < va.size(); i++)
        va[i] = a.getTransform().transformPoint(a.getPoint(i));
    for (int i = 0; i < vb.size(); i++)
        vb[i] = b.getTransform().transformPoint(b.getPoint(i));

    // through every normal of a
    for (int i = 0; i < va.size(); i++) {
        int j = (i + 1) % va.size();
        sf::Vector2f normal = { -(va[j].y - va[i].y), (va[j].x - va[i].x) };

        float max_overlap_a, min_overlap_a, max_overlap_b, min_overlap_b;
        max_overlap_a = max_overlap_b = std::numeric_limits<float>::min();
        min_overlap_a = min_overlap_b = std::numeric_limits<float>::max();

        // project every point on current normal
        for (int x = 0; x < va.size(); x++) {
            float q = dot_projection(va[x], normal);
            max_overlap_a = std::max(max_overlap_a, q);
            min_overlap_a = std::min(min_overlap_a, q);
        }

        // project every point on current normal
        for (int x = 0; x < vb.size(); x++) {
            float q = dot_projection(vb[x], normal);
            max_overlap_b = std::max(max_overlap_b, q);
            min_overlap_b = std::min(min_overlap_b, q);
        }

        overlap = std::min(overlap,
            (std::min(max_overlap_a, max_overlap_b) - std::max(min_overlap_a, min_overlap_b)));

        if (!(max_overlap_b >= min_overlap_a && max_overlap_a >= min_overlap_b))
            return -1;
    }
    return overlap;
}


float Collision::dot_projection(const sf::Vector2f& a, const sf::Vector2f& b)
{
    return (a.x * b.x + a.y * b.y);
}

float Collision::deg_to_rad(float angle)
{
    return angle * 3.141592 / 180.f;
}



Your question would be easier to understand if you explained your abbreviations at least once in the question.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
